# How can I use Groovy-Grails with Adobe Flash?

Tags: flash, grails, groovy

It is possible to use Adobe Flash as view in Grails project? I want that all logic: model and controller was written on Grails, and use Adobe Flash. It's will be perfect to have some link on examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [BlazeDS plug-in for Grails](http://marceloverdijk.blogspot.com/2008/01/blazeds-test-drive-sample-in-grails.html) and you should be all set.  You can find it [here](http://www.grails.org/Flex+Plugin).  Here's an [example](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_grails.html) of how to use it.

Comment: There is also a http://www.grails.org/plugin/flex-scaffold flex scaffolding plugin that may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what type of application you want to develop. The easiest way is to have your flash component communicate to your application through custom api - using JSON or XML. This is what we've done for [Sky Songs](http://songs.sky.com), the player component communicate directly to our grails app.

Answer (score 0):

[GraniteDS Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/gdsflex) for grails is another good option